# Shortcut created when mount any drive

Tags: linux-mint, mount

I am using Linux Mint 17.3. When I mount any drive partition, a shortcut is created on my desktop with the drive name. How can I stop this shortcut creation process?

Comment: How do you mount the drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which desktop environment you are using, but assuming it's Cinnamon, this is how:

- Open your **Menu** from the panel and click on **System Settings**
- Scroll down and click on the **Desktop** preference icon
- Uncheck "**Mounted Volumes**" under the option of what to display on the desktop

That will disable the display of that drive on your desktop, but it will not unmount the drive or modify it.

Comment: Most desktop environments have this setting somewhere.